# Event in outlook application object model to know when the first click happens on message body box?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I am developing a add-in to perform some actions when the first click happens on the message box in outlook (2013 version). I want to capture the Outlook.MailItem.Recipients as soon as the first click happens on message body box.

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach to do this (just did a quick test, seems to work for 2013):

1. Register to NewInspector event of the Application object:

   Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += ....;
2. In the event handler, register to the following event:

   var editor = newInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
   editor.Application.WindowSelectionChange += ....;

The handler fires when the selection changes, which is also happening when the user clicks the window.
Please note that you must keep references to all objects in this sample, else the event registrations will get lost.